# I have been awarded the Yearling badge 3 times in the last 2 days

Tags: support, badges, yearling-badge

I'm not complaining but I suspect a bug. I've been awarded the Yearling badge 3 times now in the last two days. Is it a bug?

Comment: Did you earn it for participating at different sites?

Comment: No, here on meta. I posted two answers and the yearling badges started rolling in. Was a strange experience. Years flew by sort to speak.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign). You do not have to earn 200 reputation in a year; the number of Yearling badges you have is simply the minimum of (reputation/200) and (account age in years). That means that if you have an old, inactive account and suddenly get a lot of reputation, you get [multiple Yearling badges in a short period](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/13/yearling?userid=214343).

Comment: Okay. Never realized it worked like that. Thanks for explaining.